# Test pollution occuring in Rails for one model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

For some reason I have one model in my app that's getting persisted to the database by tests, even though I'm using transactional tests.

```rb
    require_relative '../test_helper'

    class MapOnlyUserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
      test 'minimally reproduce my problem' do
        customer = Customer.create(name: "test@problem.com",
                                    email: "test@problem.com",
                                    vendor_id: 3,
                                    use_km_default: 0,
                                    default_speed_limit: 70)
        new_user = User.create(email: customer.email,
                               username: customer.email,
                               primary_role: 3,
                               enabled: 0,
                               email_verified: 0,
                               customer_id: customer.id)
        detailed_user = MapOnlyUser.create(user: new_user,
                                      name: "I live rent-free in your database",
                                      customer: customer)
      end
    end
```

After every run of this test the `user` and `customer` objects are cleaned up as expected, but the `detailed_user` gets persisted to my test database. What's even weirder is that there are other models (e.g. `WebAdminUser`) that could play the role of a `detailed_user`, but this is the only one that's affected.
The logs for the test shows it inside the transaction as expected:

```
----------------------------------------------------
MapOnlyUserTest: test_minimally_reproduce_my_problem
----------------------------------------------------
   (0.6ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  Customer Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `customers` WHERE `customers`.`name` = 'test@problem.com' LIMIT 1
  Timezone Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `timezones`.* FROM `timezones` WHERE `timezones`.`id` = 158 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO `customers` (`name`, `email`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `sidebar_account_tz`, `business_hours_account_tz`, `reports_account_tz`, `vendor_id`) VALUES ('test@problem.com', 'test@problem.com', '2021-04-16 11:39:34', '2021-04-16 11:39:34', 1, 1, 1, 3)
   (0.3ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
   (0.4ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  Customer Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `customers`.* FROM `customers` WHERE `customers`.`id` = 1006070975 LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`username` = 'test@problem.com' LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'test@problem.com' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `email`, `enabled`, `primary_role`, `customer_id`, `created_at`, `activation_token`) VALUES ('test@problem.com', 'test@problem.com', 0, 3, 1006070975, '2021-04-16 11:39:34', 'TJ3qiQqz0G')
   (0.3ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
   (0.3ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO `map_only_users` (`name`, `user_id`, `customer_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('I live rent-free in your database', 35953, 1006070975, '2021-04-16 11:39:34', '2021-04-16 11:39:34')
   (0.3ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
   (0.5ms)  ROLLBACK
```

I'm using rails (5.1.7) and mysql2 (0.5.3).

The code of the offending class:

```rb
class MapOnlyUser < ApplicationRecord

  validates :name, presence: { message: 'must be present!' }

  belongs_to :user, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :customer_group, optional: :true
  has_many :users_vehicles, :foreign_key => :user_id, :primary_key => :user_id
  has_many :vehicles, through: :users_vehicles

end
```

EDIT: I've noticed something of interest in schema.rb:

```rb
  create_table "map_only_users", id: :integer, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
# ... stuff
  end
```

I've no idea why, but most other tables in the Database are using InnoDB as an ENGINE. This is the first thing I've found that sounds like it might be the root of the problem.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Does MapOnlyUser have any after_commit callbacks or anything of that sort?

Comment: No but thanks for pointing out that I omitted that.

Comment: This is very strange. Are u able to drop the test db and rebuild it?

Comment: Done that, didn't help. There's about 30 tests in my suite that have this problem, consistently. Any that create a MapOnlyUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.a2hosting.co.uk/kb/developer-corner/mysql/working-with-mysql-database-engines:

> About MySQL database engines Database engines provide the underlying
> functionality for MySQL to work with and process data.
>
> The two most common and popular MySQL database engines are MyISAM and
> InnoDB. MyISAM is the default engine for MySQL for versions earlier
> than 5.5.5, and functions well in most scenarios. However, depending
> on your needs, there are situations where another database engine,
> such as InnoDB, may be the better choice. For example, InnoDB supports
> transactions, whereas MyISAM does not. InnoDB also provides support
> for foreign keys, whereas MyISAM does not.

So the Rails approach to test isolation of wrapping each test in a transaction which gets rolled back isn't going to work for models defined against tables with MyISAM as an engine. There's another much older question where people debate solutions to this: [Rails Unit Testing with MyISAM Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616173/rails-unit-testing-with-myisam-tables)